# What module instance should be passed to CreateCursor method?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui

CreateCursor function takes HINSTANCE as a first argument as described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648385(v=vs.85).aspx

It can be NULL but why is it required on the first place? My guess is that it can be used to find app main window and determine display driver to be used for cursor creation. But maybe someone have a better explanation?

Comment: Since it can be NULL it's not required at all - the function just ignores the value. Maybe in Win16 it was important and has just been kept for compatibility, or maybe it was added for future expansion and never used. There's no such concept as "app main window" btw.

Comment: My guess is that it's there incase the parameter needs to be used to load or refer to any resources in the calling application, similar to LoadCursor, which creates a custom cursor based on a resource. So it follows similar convention imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 system the handle is not used at all. Here is the disassembly with a few added comments:

```
0:000> u createcursor
USER32!CreateCursor:
00000000`77a40cb4 488bc4          mov     rax,rsp
00000000`77a40cb7 48895808        mov     qword ptr [rax+8],rbx
00000000`77a40cbb 48896810        mov     qword ptr [rax+10h],rbp
00000000`77a40cbf 48897018        mov     qword ptr [rax+18h],rsi
00000000`77a40cc3 48897820        mov     qword ptr [rax+20h],rdi
00000000`77a40cc7 4154            push    r12
00000000`77a40cc9 4881ecc0000000  sub     rsp,0C0h
00000000`77a40cd0 33db            xor     ebx,ebx
0:000> u
USER32!CreateCursor+0x1e:
00000000`77a40cd2 458be1          mov     r12d,r9d
00000000`77a40cd5 418bf8          mov     edi,r8d
00000000`77a40cd8 3bd3            cmp     edx,ebx
00000000`77a40cda 8bf2            mov     esi,edx

;  If xHotSpot is negative, return error
00000000`77a40cdc 0f8c60070100    jl      USER32!CreateCursor+0xb0 (00000000`77a51442)
00000000`77a40ce2 413bd1          cmp     edx,r9d

;  If xHotSpot is greater than nWidth return error
00000000`77a40ce5 0f8f57070100    jg      USER32!CreateCursor+0xb0 (00000000`77a51442)
00000000`77a40ceb 443bc3          cmp     r8d,ebx
0:000> u
USER32!CreateCursor+0x36:

;  If yHotSpot is negative, return error
00000000`77a40cee 0f8c4e070100    jl      USER32!CreateCursor+0xb0 (00000000`77a51442)
00000000`77a40cf4 8bac24f0000000  mov     ebp,dword ptr [rsp+0F0h]
00000000`77a40cfb 443bc5          cmp     r8d,ebp

;  If yHotSpot is greater than nHeight return error
00000000`77a40cfe 0f8f3e070100    jg      USER32!CreateCursor+0xb0 (00000000`77a51442)

;  This LEA overwrites whatever was passed in as the application handle!!!
;  RCX was not saved before this point, so handle is lost
00000000`77a40d04 488d4c2430      lea     rcx,[rsp+30h]
00000000`77a40d09 33d2            xor     edx,edx
00000000`77a40d0b 41b888000000    mov     r8d,88h
00000000`77a40d11 e8828affff      call    USER32!memset (00000000`77a39798)
```